# scrapyd deploy shows 0 spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy for a project. I ran the following commands for deploying the project :

`$scrapy deploy -l`

Then i got the following o/p:

scrapysite           `http://localhost:6800/`

`$cat scrapy.cfg`

```
[settings] 
default = scrapBib.settings

[deploy:scrapysite]  
url = http://localhost:6800/  
project = scrapBib
```

`$scrapy deploy scrapysite -p scrapBib`

```
'Building egg of scrapBib-1346242513
'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it

'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it

'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

Deploying scrapBib-1346242513 to `http://localhost:6800/addversion.json`

2012-08-29 17:45:14+0530 [HTTPChannel,22,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2012:12:15:13 

+0000] "POST /addversion.json HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"

Server response (200):

{"status": "ok", "project": "scrapBib", "version": "1346242513", "spiders": 0}
```

As you can see, getting spiders as 0 , although i have written 3 spiders inside project/spiders/ folder. As as result i am unable to start the crawl with curl requests. Please help

Comment: What version of Scrapy are you using? What directory are you trying to deploy from relative to the scrapy.cfg file? Can you post the code from your scrapy.cfg file? Could you also post your settings.py file?

Comment: I run into the same issue with Scrapy 0.14.4 and get similar messages like those above. I'm trying to deploy from the same directory where `scrapy.cfg` is in. The project seems to be uploaded correctly, but no spiders are available. I just use the default settings in `scrapy.cfg` that were created with the project. You can see them at the bottom of [my recently asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221937/cannot-import-either-scrapys-settings-module-or-its-scrapy-cfg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i also faced this issue once , do two things

1) remove `project.egg-info`, `build`, `setup.py` from your local system.

2) remove all deployed version from your server .

then try to deploy it will be fixed ...

Comment: I have two server where i have deployed the scrapy project and both suddenly stopped working....these are the error i am getting ..i have tried deleting all the files you mentioned ...but nothing so far....Here have look at my issue .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340357/unable-to-deploy-scrapy-project