# Cannot import either Scrapy's settings module or its scrapy.cfg

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, scrapy

This is a quite lengthy post, but after doing extensive research I couldn't find a solution. I have a mixed Django 1.4.1 / Scrapy 0.14.4 project on OSX 10.8 and I control Scrapy with the Django project's `manage.py` command as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197627/1125413). For instance, calling

```
python manage.py scrapy crawl example_spider
```

works without a problem. Now I'm at the point where I want to setup the `scrapyd` web service to deploy my spiders. However, when I execute

```
python manage.py scrapy server
```

then I get this exception:

```
scrapy.exceptions.NotConfigured: Unable to find scrapy.cfg file to infer project data dir
```

So, apparently Scrapy cannot find the `scrapy.cfg` file because I don't execute it from within the Scrapy project. The other Scrapy commands work, however, because in my Django project's `settings.py` I did the following:

```
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/my/Scrapy/project')
os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_scrapy_project_name.settings'
```

**Question 1:** Why can't Scrapy detect the `scrapy.cfg` file in my setup? How can I resolve this?

---

Since the stuff mentioned above doesn't work, I tried to get the `scrapyd` server running using just the `scrapy` command from within my Scrapy project directory. Executing `scrapy server` from the top-level directory of my Scrapy project yields the following:

```
$ scrapy server
UserWarning: Cannot import scrapy settings module my_scrapy_project_name.settings
warnings.warn("Cannot import scrapy settings module %s" % scrapy_module)
2012-08-31 21:58:31+0200 [-] Log opened.
2012-08-31 21:58:32+0200 [-] Scrapyd web console available at http://localhost:6800/
2012-08-31 21:58:32+0200 [Launcher] Scrapyd started: max_proc=8, runner='scrapyd.runner'
2012-08-31 21:58:32+0200 [-] Site starting on 6800
2012-08-31 21:58:32+0200 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x101dd3d88>
```

The server is running without a problem, however, the `settings.py` file of my Scrapy project cannot be found because the respective environment variable is not set anymore. That's why I do the following in my terminal:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/my/Scrapy/project
export SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_scrapy_project_name.settings
```

Unfortunately, these two commands have no effect. Whenever I execute `scrapy server` (or any other Scrapy command), I get the message that Scrapy cannot import its project's settings module.

My `scrapy.cfg` only has the following content at the moment:

```
[settings]
default = my_scrapy_project_name.settings

[deploy:scrapyd]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = my_scrapy_project_name
```

When I try to deploy my Scrapy project to the `scrapyd` server, it seems to work at first, but then I realized that none of the spiders have been uploaded, probably because the settings file could not be detected. Here is the console output:

```
$ scrapy deploy scrapyd -p my_scrapy_project_name
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/scrapy/utils/project.py:17: UserWarning: Cannot import scrapy
settings module my_scrapy_project_name.settings
 warnings.warn("Cannot import scrapy settings module %s" %
scrapy_module)
Building egg of event_crawler-1346531706
'build/lib' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Deploying event_crawler-1346531706 to http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "ok", "project": "my_scrapy_project_name", "version": "1346531706", "spiders": 0}
```

**Question 2:** How to do the correct export of the path and environment variable above so that this warning disappears?

**Question 3:** Since the `scrapyd` server seems to work fine though, how can I upload my spiders correctly?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [code branch that raises this exception](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1e2efe5664/scrapy/utils/project.py#L30) and the [definition of the `closest_scrapy_cfg` function](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1e2efe5664/scrapy/utils/conf.py#L24) that it calls, the only place scrapy is looking for your scrapy.cfg is in the dir you run the command from and any parent directory. You can maybe run `os.chdir` in your manage.py, or move your scrapy.cfg to the directory you're running from.

Comment: I've already tried to move the `scrapy.cfg` file to the same directory where the `manage.py` file is. It works, but the problem that none of my spiders are uploaded to the server still exists. The export of the environment variables does not work.