# unable to deploy scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Suddenly my scrapy deployment is started getting failed :

```
sudo scrapy deploy default -p eScraper
Password:
Building egg of eScraper-1372327569
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
eScraper.settings: module references __file__
eScraperInterface.settings: module references __file__
Deploying eScraper-1372327569 to http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/eScraper-1372327569-NEM0fx.egg/images'"}
```

Can someone tell me whats happening...

I deleted all the build folder and other created by scrapy during deployment Now it is giving me this error:

```
sudo scrapy deploy default -p eScraper
Building egg of eScraper-1372328423
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
eScraper.settings: module references __file__
eScraperInterface.settings: module references __file__
Deploying eScraper-1372328423 to http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "ok", "project": "eScraper", "version": "1372328423", "spiders": 0}
```

But i have 30 spiders inside spiders folder.....can someone help me please........

Comment: The second error isn't an error... doesn't "status": "ok" mean the deploy worked?

Comment: Yeah but it states there is no spider in my project whereas ....there are 30 spiders in my project......can you tell me why is that..

Comment: What this line means.....`[Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/eScraper-1372327569-NEM0fx.egg/images'`

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Comment: Sometimes it happens just delete older version as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue , i deleted some older deployed versions and it started to work. you should also delete some older deployed versions.